# better way to call a function from view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a function that returns a difference of two dates
 Since the dates are generated from database there can be multiple records that needs to call this function.

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%y Year %m Month' )
   {
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat);
   }
```

now what i have to do is i have to call this function from view since there can be multiple date differences in a page.
And It is not very professional to keep the logic in the view.

Comment: well I also found this solution to the problem. In controller: 
`return view('viewpage', ['controller' => $this]);`
this will send the object of the controller which then is used to call the function.  In View: 
`$controller->dateDifference($date1, $date2);`
But I am still not sure if this is a better way of calling the function from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you have a collection / array over which you're iterating in your view, so my suggestion would be that you should manipulate all the logic in the controller and then send that manipulated data to the view like this:

I'm taking your data as a collection, you can use [`mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-mapwithkeys) method of collection to add data to your current data like this:

In your controller:

```
$data = collect([...array...]); // This is your data which you can get from DB
$manipulatedData = $data->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['dateDiff'] => dateDifference($item['date1'], $item['date2'])]; // Use your method here
});
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach($manipulatedData as $data)
    <div>{{ $data->dateDiff }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper  class   and  register it in  app/config/app.php as  alias

Example :

```
<?php
namespace app\Service;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Poznet\PPAL\Helpers\Slider;
use Poznet\PPAL\Models\Config as Konfig;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class FrontendService
{
    public static function Config($name){
   // put  your  logic  here as  foo :) 

        return $foo;
    }
}
```

in config/app.php

```
    'aliases' => [
...
    'Frontend'  => 'App\Service\FrontendService'
    ],
```

And  in view  you can use

```
{{ Frontend::config('foo') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) to convert your dates column in instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) as:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'date_1',
        'date_2'
    ];
}
```

And then you can use it in your view as:

```
$date_1->diff(date_2)->format('%y Year %m Month')
```